# Compute Gain in Lottery Game in Java

Tags: java, oop

I want to implement a Lottery Game in Java and the concept is as follows, first, the player chooses 4 numbers between 1 and 20 and the amount of money he wants to bet then the draw occurs and the gain is calculated. Second, if the player found 3 good numbers among the 4 numbers he chooses, then he gets 10 times the amount of his bet and if the player found 4 good numbers among the 4 numbers he choose, then he gets 100 times the amount of his bet.

And in the Bet class, I did this

```
public class Bet {

//Method to compute Gain
public int computeGain(Lottery lottery) {
    ArrayList<Integer> drawnNumbers = lottery.getDrawnNumbers();
    ArrayList<Integer> goodNumbers = lottery.getGoodNumbers();

    for (Integer gn : goodNumbers) {

        ArrayList<Integer> winningNumber = lottery.getGoodNumbers();

    }

    if (winningNumber.size() = 3) {
        payout = 10 * betMoney;
        return payout;
    } 
    else if (winningNumber.size() = 4) {
        payout = 100 * betmoney;
        return payout;
    } 
    else {
        return betMoney;
    }

}
```

}

I have a problem with my function computeGain which I'm kind of stuck at this point. Or may be I am doing it the wrong way. I am a beginner in Java and I'm doing my best to learn this language.
Any one can please give me some ideas on how to proceed? I'll appreciate thanks

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: cannot find symbol : variable winningNumber. something like this. it is mostly in the computeGain function

Comment: That's because you defined it inside the `for-loop`. It is not visible outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your computeGain method, just do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> winningNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>(drawnNumbers); //copy drawnNumbers list

winningNumber.retainAll(goodNumbers); //do an intersection between the lists
```

instead of

```
for (Integer gn : goodNumbers) {

    ArrayList<Integer> winningNumber = lottery.getGoodNumbers();

}
```

If you want to use a for-each loop, do it as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> winningNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //initialize outside for-each loop
for (Integer gn : goodNumbers) {

    if(drawnNumbers.contains(gn)){
          winningNumber.add(gn);
    }

}
```

Comment: inside the foreach loop? or no need for the for each loop here?

Comment: Yes, since you only want to find out which numbers in drawnNumbers are also present in goodNumbers list right? (You can also use a for-each loop there, but no need for that)

Comment: yeah , thats what I want to do. but when I do this  if (winningNumber.size() = 3) { inorder to compare the size. there is a unexpectedtype error

Comment: @LabelleDoriane use == instead of = over there

Comment: I have a missing return statement after my forloop don't know what that means? since I have return payout for each if statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182377/discussion-between-labelle-doriane-and-mettleap).